# Is Mapbox for Unity abandonware?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I'm using the latest version of unity and mapbox (2021.3.5f1 and 2.1.1).  On install of the package I get the following errors, and as a result no mapbox menu.  I'm dead at the starting line.  I noticed no updates in 3 years on github.  Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I can’t help but feel you answered your own question. You have access to the same info we do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox hasnt updated SDK for Unity after their last update - SDK for Unity 2017. And Unity changed several classes name like ARBackgroundRenderer to ARCamera. You can change all variable names with error issue to recent one finding in Unity document, But I dont wanna recomment this cause I tried, and i failed.  So, if you wanna use mapbox in unity, you have two choices - 1. downgrade Unity to 2018 version. 2. Delete scripts of Mapbox SDK related with AR.

Check this link :https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-unity-sdk/issues/1753

Im currently using unity 2020.3.30f1 right now, and I deleted all scripts related with AR of Mapbox,And I installed AR Foundation.